# Azure Search API does not find indexed document despite correct query

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

Using Azure Search REST API v2016-09-01, the following query find the expected document:

```
?queryType=full&search=id:3119443 AND name:du*
```

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 4.425995,
      "id": "3119443",
      "name": "dupond"
    }
  ]
}
```

Whereas the following broader query (searching `d*` instead of `du*`) does not find the same document:

```
?queryType=full&search=id:3119443 AND name:d*
```

```json
{
  "value": []
}
```

The `name` field uses a custom analyzer with the `Whitespace` tokenizer and the `WordDelimiterTokenFilter`, `AsciiFoldingTokenFilter` and `Lowercase` token filters.

---

- Most of the indexed documents are correctly found when searching their first `name` letter.
- The issue is 100% reproducible on those specific documents, for which I don't find anything special.
- The Search Service is a "Standard" tier (1 replica, 1 partition, 1 search unit), with the index containing 3,000,000+ documents.

---

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I am Nate from Azure Search. This appears to be a bug. We are looking into the issue. Feel free to contact me at nateko@microsoft.com if you have any questions.

Comment: This is a regression introduced in a recent change. The change introduce a cap on how many terms a wildcard search query can expand to and affects queries that are widely scoped such a* or /.*/. We are treating this as a bug and are actively working on a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. As commented, this is a regression introduced in a recent change. The bug has been fixed. Thanks.